# Camera not working for app in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I have search all over the web to try help with this camera plugin for phonegap. I have installed the camera plugin correctly from the PhoneGap api website. I have set the plugin permission and feature to the config.xml. I have added the javascript to the camera page and calling it through the button. please could someone just help me out in just fixing the problem that the app is not calling up the camera on the android device.

Here is my coding for my config file (config.xml)

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.test.TestApp_JN" version="1.0.0">
  <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="plugins.cordova-plugin-camera.src.android.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
  <name>JN_TestApp</name>
  <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <content src="camera.html"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <gap:plugin name="plugins.cordova-plugin-camera" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="add" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    </gap:config-file>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Here is my coding for the camera.html page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<title>Camera</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="camera" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Camera</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                    <div align="center">
                    <button style="border-color: blue;"  onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
                    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
                    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
                    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
                    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
                    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                            var pictureSource;   // picture source
                            var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

                            // Wait for device API libraries to load
                            //
                            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

                            // device APIs are available
                            //
                            function onDeviceReady() {
                                pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                                destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
                            }

                            // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
                            //
                            function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
                              // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
                              // console.log(imageData);

                              // Get image handle
                              //
                              var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

                              // Unhide image elements
                              //
                              smallImage.style.display = 'block';

                              // Show the captured photo
                              // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
                              //
                              smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                            }

                            // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
                            //
                            function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
                              // Uncomment to view the image file URI
                              // console.log(imageURI);

                              // Get image handle
                              //
                              var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

                              // Unhide image elements
                              //
                              largeImage.style.display = 'block';

                              // Show the captured photo
                              // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
                              //
                              largeImage.src = imageURI;
                            }

                            // A button will call this function
                            //
                            function capturePhoto() {
                              // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
                              navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
                            }

                            // A button will call this function
                            //
                            function capturePhotoEdit() {
                              // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
                              navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
                                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
                            }

                            // A button will call this function
                            //
                            function getPhoto(source) {
                              // Retrieve image file location from specified source
                              navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
                                destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                                sourceType: source });
                            }

                            // Called if something bad happens.
                            //
                            function onFail(message) {
                              alert('Failed because: ' + message);
                            }

    </script>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" class="bottom">
                <h4>J.Newport</h4>
            </div>
</div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>


</html>
```

I am currently using Dreamweaver for the coding of the webpages and phonegap. I have search for a very long time to try resolve this problem i'm having. Please could someone just just this coding and just let me know where i must fix in order to get the camera to work on my app.

Much appreciated

Comment: Please show what error message. Your question  not clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed camera plugin and used your code (camera.html) worked fine for me. As you have not mentioned the app, i changed it to

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
receivedEvent: function(id) {
}
};

app.initialize();
}
```

Is it showing you any error??

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was a small mistake which I picked up. And i forgot to work with the device ready listener. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue few days ago, my app works in Phonegap Desktop but not in Build.
I used camera and media plugin, but it didn' work in app, only in desktop.
Today,  I found a solution. Another plugin is necessary in config.xml:

`<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-media-stream" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />`

Now it works fine.